# How to tint local icon image with transparent background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have looked into multiple solutions, but I could not find one that is suitable for what I need.

I have this **local image**

[image]
When I hover the image I need to change only the black background to my theme color. A hover image is not a good solution because the theme color changes and it's difficult to get from the designer an image each time.

I have tried drawing the local image from both local source and from hidden div. And after that reading bit by bit and changing only the black bits to my theme color.

```
<div style='display: block'>
    <img id='img' src='back-icon-64.png' width='32' height='32' />
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=32 height=32>
```

The JavaScript

```
function drawImage() {

    var hiddenImg = document.getElementById('img')
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    var image = new Image(32, 32)
    image.src = hiddenImg.src
    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 32, 32)
    }
}

function recolor(ctx) {

    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 32, 32);
    var data = imgData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        red = data[i + 0];
        green = data[i + 1];
        blue = data[i + 2];
        alpha = data[i + 3];
        //console.log("rgba" + red + green, blue, alpha)
        console.log("rgba")
    }
}
drawImage()
```

Although I tried to set headers I am getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
>   cross-origin data.

An working fiddle will be really helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Is just converting it to svg and hitting the `fill` color an option? `mix-blend-mode` is a good suggestion but does have some limitation on [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider `mix-blend-mode` *(you won't have transparency as you will need a white backgroud under the image)*

```css
.icon {
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi3wa.png)center/cover,
  #fff;
  position:relative;
}

.icon:hover::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--c,red);
  mix-blend-mode:lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="--c:blue;">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="--c:green;">
</div>
```

> Selects the lighter of the backdrop and source colors.
>
> The backdrop is replaced with the source where the source is lighter; otherwise, it is left unchanged.

https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#valdef-blend-mode-lighten